# Returning a student number and student average from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this function, I want to get each student number in the first innerlist  and the average of their assignment grades in the second innerlist. This is the file.

```
Last Name,First Name,Student No.,uTORid,A1,A2,A3,A4
Smith, Joe,9911991199,smithjoe9,99,88,77,66
Ash, Wood,9912334456,ashwood,11,22,33,44
Full, Kare,9913243567,fullkare,78,58,68,88
```

I get this error when I test my function

```
line 59, in <module>
marks = float(grades)
builtins.TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def student_avg(open_file):
    '''(file) -> list of list

    Given an open class list file, return a list of lists where each 
    inner list is the student number (a str) and the second is the
    average of the assignment grades for that student (a float).
    '''

    new_list = []
    for line in open_file:
        nums_list = line.split(',')
        for item in nums_list:
            stu_num = nums_list[2]
            grades = nums_list[4:]
            marks = float(grades)
            avg = sum(marks)/len(grades)
            new_list.append([stu_num, avg])
    return new_list
```

Comment: Is that stored as one variable?

Comment: try `marks = [float(g) for g in grades]`

Answer (score 0):

Float the result of `sum`.

```
def student_avg(open_file):
    '''(file) -> list of list

    Given an open class list file, return a list of lists where each 
    inner list is the student number (a str) and the second is the
    average of the assignment grades for that student (a float).
    '''
    new_list = []
    for line in open_file:
        split = line.split(',')
        student_id = split[2]
        grades = split[4:]
        average = sum(float(g) for g in grades) / len(grades)
        new_list.append([student_id, average])
    return new_list
```

By the way, I removed the second `for` as I think it does not match the problem: you would return several time the same student.

Comment: avg = float(sum(grades))/len(grades)
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
I get that error now

Comment: Oh ups! sorry I forgot about that. Notice also that you might want to skip the first line.

Comment: It automatically skips the header when I test it

Answer (score 0):

```
def student_avg(open_file):
    '''(file) -> list of list

    Given an open class list file, return a list of lists where each 
    inner list is the student number (a str) and the second is the
    average of the assignment grades for that student (a float).
    '''

    new_list = []
    for line in open_file:
        nums_list = line.split(',')
        for item in nums_list:
            stu_num = nums_list[2]
            grades = nums_list[4:]
            avg = float(sum(grades))/len(grades)
            new_list.append([stu_num, avg])
    return new_list
```

converting numerator or denominator to float would solve the purpose. If one of the grades list is a float, then sum would anyways be a float.