# changing rows into columns a list from files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anyone know how I could interleave the assignments from this file?

```
Here is the file, grades.csv and the format.

       Last Name,First Name,Student No.,uTORid,A1,A2,A3,A4
       Smith,Joe,9911991199,smithjoe9,99,88,77,66
       Ash,Wood,9912334456,ashwood,11,22,33,44
       Full,Kare,9913243567,fullkare,78,58,68,88
```

I want to get something like this and then add the total values for all the assignments and then divide by the number of assignments for each assignment to get the averages

```
       [99, 11, 78]
       [88, 22, 58]
       [77, 33, 68]
       [66, 44, 88]

def class_avg(open_file):
'''(file) -> list of float
Return a list of assignment averages for the entire class given the open
class file. The returned list should contain assignment averages in the 
order listed in the given file.  For example, if there are 3 assignments 
per student, the returned list should 3 floats representing the 3 averages.
'''

      new_list = []
for line in open_file:
    grades_list = line.split(',')
    marks1 = grades_list[4:5]
    marks2 = grades_list[6:7]

    for item in range(min(marks1, marks2)):
        added_marks = marks1[item] + marks2[item]
```

This is what I have so far, not quite sure how to continue

Comment: It's not clear at all what are you trying to do. Please include the expected output (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show us what you have tried so far, so we can help you. And please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a student number and student average from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079529/returning-a-student-number-and-student-average-from-a-file)

Comment: Another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086721/calculating-a-class-avg-from-a-file

Comment: Looks like you're asking the same question every day, **for the past three days**.

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration and iteration is your friend in this case.  And finding the average is simple with built-in functions

```
def class_avg(open_file):
    '''(file) -> list of float
    Return a list of assignment averages for the entire class given the open
    class file. The returned list should contain assignment averages in the 
    order listed in the given file.  For example, if there are 3 assignments 
    per student, the returned list should 3 floats representing the 3 averages.
    '''
    marks=[[],[],[],[]]

    for line in open_file:
        grades_list = line.strip().split(',')
        for idx,i in enumerate(range(4,8)):
            marks[idx].append(int(grades_list[i]))    
    avgs = [] 

    for mark in marks:
        avgs.append(float(sum(mark)/(len(mark))))
    return(avgs)
```

Comment: It says division by zero error when  try to test this

Comment: i changed the function to assume that you have already opened the file and that you have already iterated past the first line with something such as `next(file)` or `file.readline()`.   there is no reason you should be receiving that error with your given input as it runs on my machine...  if you edit your post to include the rest of the code i can help you debug

Comment: I mean this line avgs.append(float(sum(mark)/(len(mark)))) has a division by zero error for some reason

Comment: yes i know thats what you meant, but the length of `mark` should always be 3 with the above code, so there **should** be no zero division error, meaning that you must have done something to the file that is being passed into the function therefore leading to an error.  so if you do not post the rest of the relevant code, particularly how you open the file and what is done with it before it is passed, i cannot help any further.

Comment: I just want to get the assignment grades into [99, 11, 78] [88, 22, 58][77, 33, 68] [66, 44, 88] that

Comment: then  remove the end of the code that computes averages and just `return marks`, also while you're at it please accept this answer by clicking the grey checkmark next to it, clearly it is a sufficient answer as it has prompted another question from a student in your class, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118093/how-to-not-hardcode-function-in-this-example/47118156#47118156  for more details that may help with your hw

Answer (score 0):

Do this, I asked a similar question yesterday.

```
def class_avg(open_file):
'''(file) -> list of float
Return a list of assignment averages for the entire class given the open
class file. The returned list should contain assignment averages in the
order listed in the given file.  For example, if there are 3 assignments
per student, the returned list should 3 floats representing the 3 averages.
'''
marks = None
avgs = []
for line in open_file:
    grades_list = line.strip().split(',')
    if marks is None:
        marks = []
        for i in range(len(grades_list) -4):
            marks.append([])
    for idx,i in enumerate(range(4,len(grades_list))):
        marks[idx].append(int(grades_list[i]))
for mark in marks:
    avgs.append(float(sum(mark)/(len(mark))))
return avgs
```

Comment: I recommend you wait until you have enough rep to comment.