# How to not hardcode function in this example

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following links contain 2 csv files that the function should pass through [grades_1e_2a](https://gyazo.com/37fc971b13093f0164eba165d2e4da04)
[grades_2e_4a](https://gyazo.com/c4ac5053dfd3ff09f5fdf783d4ef4428)

However my function is only able to pass the 2nd linked file, as it is hardcoded to `range(4,8)`.
output: `[91.5, 73.5, 81.5, 91.5]`
The input file will start at the 4th element but may not necessarily end at the 8th element.

```
def class_avg(open_file):
    '''(file) -> list of float
    Return a list of assignment averages for the entire class given the open
    class file. The returned list should contain assignment averages in the
    order listed in the given file.  For example, if there are 3 assignments
    per student, the returned list should 3 floats representing the 3 averages.
    '''
    marks=[[],[],[],[]]
    avgs = []
    for line in open_file:
        grades_list = line.strip().split(',')
        for idx,i in enumerate(range(4,8)):
            marks[idx].append(float(grades_list[i]))
    for mark in marks:
        avgs.append(float(sum(mark)/(len(mark))))
    return avgs
```

How do I fix this so that my code will be able to read both files, or any file?
I have already opened the file and iterated past the first line with file.readline() in a previous function on the same file.
Thanks for everyone's help in advance.

Updated progress: https://gyazo.com/064dd0d695e3a3e1b4259a25d1b0b1a0

Comment: I did not delete any questions, this is my first question. I am a new user.

Comment: I am not bigd, just another student in his class apparently.

Comment: oh lmaooo. well glad i can help

Comment: y'all homework due on monday, huh? ..nice to see you working Sat night

Comment: Well it's due in less than 24hrs. OTL

Comment: lmaoo if you need anymore help just ask

Comment: check out the comments below @Ragib Ahsan's answer, still stuck

Comment: check my edited answer with code for the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both sets of your data start the same place the following works
`for idx,i in enumerate(range(4,len(grades_list))):`

This should fulfill all requirements that Im aware of up to this point

```
def class_avg(open_file):
    '''(file) -> list of float
    Return a list of assignment averages for the entire class given the open
    class file. The returned list should contain assignment averages in the
    order listed in the given file.  For example, if there are 3 assignments
    per student, the returned list should 3 floats representing the 3 averages.
    '''
    marks = None
    avgs = []
    for line in open_file:
        grades_list = line.strip().split(',')
        if marks is None:
            marks = []
            for i in range(len(grades_list) -4):
                marks.append([])
        for idx,i in enumerate(range(4,len(grades_list))):
            marks[idx].append(int(grades_list[i]))
    for mark in marks:
        avgs.append(float(sum(mark)/(len(mark))))
    return avgs
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
def class_avg(open_file, start = 4, end = 8):
...
...
    for idx,i in enumerate(range(start, end)):
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but the problem is we aren't allowed to change the output  method, it has to be "def class_avg(open_file)"

Comment: You need to reorganize input file as from 4th to 8th element.

Comment: The input file will start at the 4th element, but will not necessarily end at the 8th element.

Comment: You need use other delimeter for next after 8th element like ";" 
"Hello,World, 100005940,wordlh1,98,99,97,86;0001;0002;0003"
After you need to resplit return for ";" delimiter and you got all yours 0001, 0002, etc datas

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:

```
     for idx,i in enumerate(range(4,len(grades_list))):
         marks[idx].append(int(grades_list[i]))
```

Considering you know how many assignments are there and initialized the marks list accordingly.

Comment: So I implemented your fix, however i got this error: line 78, in <module>
    avgs.append(float(sum(mark)/(len(mark))))
builtins.ZeroDivisionError: division by zero https://gyazo.com/064dd0d695e3a3e1b4259a25d1b0b1a0

Comment: Yes, thats because you have 4 elements in marks, but you have only two assignments. So, the rest two are empty which has length zero. So, either initialize the marks with exactly two elements (which is hard coding, would fail if in another file there are three assignments) or initialize the marks list after reading the first line where you can get how many assignments are there.

Comment: So I want to do the 2nd method you suggested. Do you mean that I should write marks = [] right before the first for loop?

Comment: Also, the first line of your file is a header, it doesn't have any scores. So, you should read that line even before the loop. So, you can do something like this: header = open_file.readline(); then marks = [[]] * (len(header) - 4) right before the loop.

Comment: Ok I just edited the question for clarification: so I already opened the file and iterated past the first line with file.readline() in a previous function on the same file.

Comment: Ok, then either pass (len(header) - 4) as number of assignments as a second parameter in this function, or initialize the marks variable as a None and then put an if statement inside the loop where you check whether marks is None, if it is then assign marks = [[]] * (len(grades_list) - 4)

Comment: @RagibAhsan you cannot multiply like that to create your lists, than you are creating four references to the same list and all data is stored together

Comment: you have to do something like.. `if marks is None:`
         `marks = []`
         `for i in range(len(grades_list) -4):`
          `marks.append([])`

Comment: @0TTT0: Thanks man for pointing that out. Missed it. Here is the thing I'm suggesting for option 1: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25892513/, option 2: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25892512/

Comment: hey @RagibAhsan, im liking that list comp

Comment: @RagibAhsan If I use your option 2 method, I get the following error message: line 74, in <module>
    if marks in None:
builtins.TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: @cboost: Sorry for a type, that "in" should be "is", like: "if marks is None"